# Audio loss after automatic 20.04 update - updates in general

Tags: sound, updates, 20.04

I've been a happy user of Ubuntu 20.04 for a month or so and I've been taking the automatic updates. After the last one it couldn't find my audio device anymore. I tried a whole bunch of stuff to get it up again. Eventually I just had to re-format the sector and reinstall. I'm opting out of updates from now on.

> Automatically check for updates: Never

Just wondering if there is a better way to make sure I don't get a bad update.

Comment: Please troubleshoot and file a bug report when something breaks. My sound didn't break, so I have no useful troubleshooting data to share with the Ubuntu developers. If nobody reports a problem, it won't be fixed.